# Deploying Python Bokeh charts in shared cpanel hosting

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to deploy an web apps in written in python with Bokeh charts.I want to show the charts in a shared hosting web server, which runs in cpanel. Is it possible? Do I need vps?

Comment: Depends on your web host. Contact their support department.

Comment: i am using inmotion hosting